# How can I programmatically create an Excel "sort/Filter combobox"?

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

I'm reverse-engineering a manually created spreadsheet for dynamic creation. Most of the cells are populated with simple data, but there are a couple that are "sort/Filter" dropdowns like so:

[image]

How can I dynamically create such a control?

Is there a way to "view source" in the Excel spreadsheet to see what sort of code might be required to produce these controls?

### UPDATE

Adapting MacroMark's code, this compiles:

```
var rangeMonthYears = _xlSheet.Range[_xlSheet.Cells[7, 3], _xlSheet.Cells[7, 15]];
        object sortFilterCombobox = (object)rangeMonthYears.AutoFilter(1, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, XlAutoFilterOperator.xlAnd, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, true);
        _xlSheet.Cells["6", "C"] = sortFilterCombobox; //MonthLabel;
```

...but it crashes, presenting me with this upbraiding note:

[image]

How have I gone astray?

### UPDATE 2

To answer MacroMarc in his comment below, here is a screen shot of the filter control in the legacy/model spreadsheet (which I'm reverse-engineering):

[image]

In this case, I deselected "November" from the list, so that it was removed, as you can see. So what the user selects affects the visibility of the columns below.

### UPDATE 3

With all this fancy-pantsiness baked into the legacy spreadsheet, I'm now considering saving it as a template and simply replacing the cell contents as needed. Is there any reason why this would not be viable?

If not, to accomplish this, should I save the existing spreadhseet "As Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook"?

### UPDATE 4

I tried adapting MacroMarc's answer like so:

```
Range monthYearCells = _xlSheet.Range[_xlSheet.Cells[COLUMN_HEADING_ROW, MONTH1_COL], _xlSheet.Cells[COLUMN_HEADING_ROW, MONTH13_COL]];
object monthFilter = (object)monthYearCells.AutoFilter(1, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, XlAutoFilterOperator.xlAnd, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, true);
var monthFilterCell = (Range)_xlSheet.Cells[6, 3];
monthFilterCell.Value = monthFilter;
```

...but got the runtime exception:

[image]

Is it the last line (assigning monthFilter to the range's Value property) that's causing the problem? If so, what *should* I assign monthFilter to, or what should I do with it?

Comment: Ah I see. The code I gave you was just to enable 'filter dropdowns' in an Excel range. They appear at the top row of that range automatically. It seems you want to capture twelve months of the year from Excel cells across a row, and  display them in a dropdown in completely different cell. i.e. you want the 'filter dropdown' to be transferred. Not gonna work with that syntax/object. This could lead to problem after problem. Perhaps it is best if you explain what you wish to achieve and we'll try to give you best advice. 'Filter dropdowns' are a feature that drop down at the top of a column .

Comment: Just to check does it work in the Excel sheet for you if you comment out the "_xlSheet.Cells["6", "C"] = sortFilterCombobox; //MonthLabel;" line?? Do you see filter dropdowns for each month then? Just checking that part... There are all sorts of filters in Excel including pivot table filters which are more tricky. Not really sure what the purpose of your C# application is...

Comment: Please see Update 3; all I have on my programmatically-created sheet so far is a lable that says "Month" there - it's just a placeholder until I find out how to create the sort/filter combobox.

Comment: The "More commands" option is inside the menu illustrated in the first screenshot I posted, not the second. To see the developer tab options in the second window, choose "Developer Tab" from the drop-down at the very top of what is illustrated in the second screenshot (the combo box with the label "choose commands from").

Comment: Also, I found the cause of your problem and have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes, Isaw where the "More Commands" is expected, but I don't have it; at least, I don't see it (I think it's Excel 2007, although I see no "Properties" menu item that would verify that - 2007 is what is in "All Programs" in my Start menu.

Comment: Ok. Looks like you might be in a pivot table. Can you confirm this? If you click on sep 14, you should see a new coloured tab pop on the ribbon saying Pivot Table Tools.

Comment: Yep, exactly (clicking any of the months causes the title bar to get a new "Pivot Table Tools" tattoo).

Comment: I thought so from your latest screenshot. You have a pivot table filter which is **automatically** created for Pivot Tables by Excel. So instead of trying to reverse engineer this, you need to just figure out where the pivot table is being created from(data source range etc). Clay, I see you're a C# coder with 8.5k points, so you know your way around programming, but this is gonna become an Excel pivot table tutorial if we keep on. I hope you get help, but my best solution for you is to study on pivot tables, and how they're created. Also accept that you won't be able to just create a filter.

Comment: A pivot table takes its data source from some range of data on an Excel sheet(could be a different sheet in same workbook, could be same sheet). You CAN create a pivot table from C# though, so good news there. The filters automatically appear by default for each field selected to be displayed in the pivot tabel( like your months are). To find out more about a pivot table's data etc, you need to explore the pivot table tabs on the Ribbon i.e. things like Data source, data labels etc...

Comment: Re your latest update, yes you should focus on trying to change the data source range for your pivot table in the template. As for Macro-enabled, it only need to be macro enabled if VBA code is being run as part of the workbook functionality. Transforming the file into new versions via C# Interop isn't VBA coding, so no need to do this. It doent really matter but macro-enabled files may present a security barrier on some systems.

Comment: Why would I change the data source range? The rows/columns affected will always be the same 13.

Comment: Those columns are aggregating data from somewhere else. That range would differ month to month, year to year.

Comment: I'm taking care of computing and adding the data programmatically; what I'm after is the displaying/hiding of selected months, or displaying them "oldest to newest" or "newest to oldest" - that's all the existing filter does.

Comment: See update to my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filters are created natively by the range being in an Excel table, or maybe by Filter button on Excel interface. As Joshua said you can try and script this in VBA, but it seems by your question tags that you are using C# and Excel-Interop(??)

Try using the range object handle in your C# code and applying .Autofilter method.

```
object result = (object)oRange.AutoFilter(1, System.Reflection.Missing.Value,ExApp.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlAnd,System.Reflection.Missing.Value, true);
```

where above ExApp is my alias for the Interop.Excel namespace.

As for Developer tab, look at the Customize Ribbon option on google for your Excel version. Rightclick ribbon maybe, or File-->Options--etc

**UPDATE**

Ok so to amend the sort and filter properties of a pivotfield, you need to grab the handle to the pivotField, e.g if your 'Month' Filter was in cell D5, you could do something like:

```
Range oRange = oSheet.get_Range("D5", "D5");
PivotField pf = oRange.PivotField;
pf.AutoSort((int)XlSortOrder.xlDescending, "Month");   //this sorts in reverse order            
pf.PivotItems(2).Visible = false;   //this makes the second item deselected in filter
```

Comment: Thanks; please see Update 2.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot "view source" on an Excel spreadsheet. However, you can open up the VBA editor and see what code has been written into it. In modern versions of Excel, how to do so might not be so apparent. Up at the top of the Excel window, look for the small arrow, click it, and a drop-down will appear.

[image]

Toward the bottom of the list, you will see an option titled "more commands". Click there and the following window opens.

[image]

You can then filter the list of commands. Choose "developer tab" and on the right side you will see a command titled "Visual Basic". You also have other commands for recording macros, so add the entire list. As you can see from my first screenshot, I have already added these on my copy of Excel.

Please be advised that you may also need to adjust your security settings.

Now that you know how to open the VBA editor, and you have the macro commands, you can view the code that created the filter, or you could create a filter yourself and record a macro to see how it is done. The resulting macro will be in VBA and you can modify it however you would like.

First click the Quick Access Toolbar icon for "record macro", and then add the filter by selecting a cell in the top row of table you want to filter, and  then click the data tab; click filter.

After recording your macro, you should see something in the VBA editor like this:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$D$6").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="1023123"
    Selection.AutoFilter
End Sub
```

Now that we have covered the whole "open source" issue, here is the solution for the interop issue. I have taken your code, changed it, and tested it to reproduce the error and have discovered what the problem is. The procedure must be selecting only a part of the table or a completely empty area of the spreadsheet. When Excel tries to find the corners of the range to be filtered, it runs into a problem because there are no identifiable corners to find. Take this for example:

```
    Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
    app.Visible = true;
    Excel.Workbook wk = app.Workbooks.Add();
    Excel.Worksheet sh = wk.Sheets[1];
    sh.Cells[1, 1] = "col1";
    sh.Cells[1, 2] = "col2";
    sh.Cells[1, 3] = "col3";
    sh.Cells[1, 4] = "col4";
    sh.Cells[2, 1] = "data";
    sh.Cells[2, 2] = "data";
    sh.Cells[2, 3] = "data";
    sh.Cells[2, 4] = "data";
    sh.Cells[3, 1] = "data2";
    sh.Cells[3, 2] = "data2";
    sh.Cells[3, 3] = "data2";
    sh.Cells[3, 4] = "data2";

    //Excel.Range r1 = sh.Range[sh.Cells[1, 1], sh.Cells[3, 4]]; //this works
    Excel.Range r2 = sh.Range[sh.Cells[7, 3], sh.Cells[7, 15]]; //this fails
    //object sortFilterCombobox1 = (object)r1.AutoFilter(1, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlAnd, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, true);
    object sortFilterCombobox2 = (object)r2.AutoFilter(1, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlAnd, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, true);
```

In the screenshot below, I have highlighted the row that the code tries to put a filter on and it is empty. So, what is going on here is that the code is for some reason not referencing the correct area of the spreadsheet you are working with.

One way you can fix this is to reference the 1st cell in the top row instead of the entire row. As long as there are no gaps in the table, then Excel will find the entire table.

[image]

So try applying AutoFilter on this range instead of the whole range:

```
_xlSheet.Cells[7, 3]
```

Also, I should point out in case you are not aware, but when you are assigning the "sortFilterCombobox" to a cell, you are actually popping a boolean value into the cell. The AutoFilter function returns a boolean, not the filter object itself.

Comment: Oh, it is using Interop. I will investigate and then update my answer.

Comment: Actually, 73...715 is the correct range for me; that's where the month labels exist (Sep 14, Oct 14, etc.)

Comment: Try doing the autofilter on the first cell in the row holding the column labels instead of the entire row.