# To what do I need to assign the Excel Interop Autofilter object?

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop, autofilter

This question is a "sequel" to the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33529985/how-can-i-programmatically-create-an-excel-sort-filter-combobox), but it is new enough to warrant its own place in the ether.

I need to create a filter combobox based on a range; the span of columns should then be sortable front to back (ascending/descending) and filterable by choosing which ones to display/hide.

Dervied from code provided at that former answer by MacroMarc, I think I'm close to having what I need:

```
Range monthYearCells = _xlSheet.Range[_xlSheet.Cells[COLUMN_HEADING_ROW, MONTH1_COL], _xlSheet.Cells[COLUMN_HEADING_ROW, MONTH13_COL]];
object monthFilter = (object)monthYearCells.AutoFilter(1, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, XlAutoFilterOperator.xlAnd, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, true);
var monthFilterCell = (Range)_xlSheet.Cells[6, 3];
monthFilterCell.Value = monthFilter;
```

...where I want to put the sort/filter combobox in monthFilterCell. However, adding the monthFilter object to that cell's Value property causes this runtime exception:

[image]

So to what, precisely, do I assign monthFilter, if not to Value, whichis an object (as opposed to Value2, which s a String)?

Am I close, or missing the boat entirely?

Note: I also tried this code, also based on some from MacroMarc:

```
Range monthYearCells = _xlSheet.Range[_xlSheet.Cells[COLUMN_HEADING_ROW, MONTH1_COL], _xlSheet.Cells[COLUMN_HEADING_ROW, MONTH13_COL]];
PivotField pf = monthYearCells.PivotField;
```

...but it fails, too:

[image]

Comment: Clay, I just wondered about this spreadsheet that you are recreating. Why are you not just using C# to recreate a pivot table and populate the data source of a pivot table. I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but pivot tables are there for a reason. They have a lot of built-in functionality and have the sort/filter, so why so determined to recreate the display without a pivot table??

I fear you may be giving yourself unwarranted headache...

Comment: Thanks, MM; I'll look into that on the next one; this one is down to the Gingerbread, though, so I'm not going to do any more heavy refactoring with it.